# How to localize InfoPlist.strings manually?

Tags: xcode, localization

My mistake, I uncheck "Use Base Internationalization" in Info section of XCode project. So add Localization and check "Use Base Internationalization", but do not create any Localization.

[image]
[image]

I want to localize InfoPlist.strings. How to recover localization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create an string file, and name it "InfoPlist.strings", then select the file and click "localize" in property window. Now your problem should be resolved!